# Getting null value of Property even when set default to empty string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, null, migration

I'm migrating my project from `MVC 2` to `MVC 5`, when I'm sending `model` value to `controller` then BE property holder is containing property `FilterProjectStatusItems`, its default value is "" but it is showing null at run time.

```
 [DefaultValue("")]
  public string FilterProjectStatusItems { get; set; }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWZT9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use a constructor

```
public class Model
{
    public string FilterProjectStatusItems  { get; set; }  

    public Model()
    { 

        PropertyInfo[] properties = GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach(var propertyInfo in properties)
        {
          if(propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string))
          {
            propertyInfo.SetValue(this, String.Empty, null);
          };
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having number of properties, it will be bottle neck for me to update all of them. Is there any other solution?